# Modify JSON Array labels

Tags: javascript, json

Does anyone know how to modify the labels in a JSON Array?

Lets say my array is:

```
[{"Device_ID":"43","Image":"Amazon-Kindle-Fire.png","Manufacturer":"Amazon","Model":"Kindle Fire","Type":"Tablet"},{"Device_ID":"43","Image":"Apple-iPad.png","Manufacturer":"Apple","Model":"iPad","Type":"Tablet"}]
```

How can I manipulate it so that Device_ID becomes label and the combination of Manufacturer and Model becomes values?

This is required for the jquery autocomplete and I am unable to modify the current JSON Array at source

UPDATE:

Currently attempting this way with no success:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
    var john = availableTags.forEach(function(v){v.Device_ID = v.Manufacturer + v.Model});
    $("#search_input").autocomplete({
        source: john;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What have you tried, what is "the combination of Manufacturer and Model" what do you mean by `Device_ID` becomes the laber? That the value of `Device_ID` will be used as the key for the "combination" in another JSON array?

Comment: Jquery autocomplete needs a label and value for MD arrays.  I need a label so i'll use Device_ID.  In this case, the new Value label would be "Amazon Kindle Fire","Apple iPad" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that:

```
o = [{"Device_ID":"43","Image":"Amazon-Kindle-Fire.png","Manufacturer":"Amazon","Model":"Kindle Fire","Type":"Tablet"},{"Device_ID":"43","Image":"Apple iPad.png","Manufacturer":"Apple","Model":"iPad","Type":"Tablet"}]
o.forEach(function(v){v.Device_ID = v.Manufacturer + " " + v.Model})
```

it will loop for every object in the array and assign the id to the combination you need.

Comment: Like so?
  var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
  var john = availableTags.forEach(function(v){v.Device_ID = v.Manufacturer + v.Model})
  $( "#search_input" ).autocomplete({
   source: john
  });

Comment: i'm not sure what your <?php echo json_encode($results); ?> returns. assuming it returns what above (in your question) it should be ok. anyway if the answer helps please mark it as answer.

Comment: Yep it returns whats in my question, however my comment above doesn't work :(

Comment: put a comma (;) before $( "#search_input"

Comment: No joy.  I've updated my question with the code I am now using

Comment: i'm answering the question above. if you'll do console.log(john) you'll see the correct values you needed. your autocomplete question is a different one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17549/discussion-between-sagivo-and-k20gh)